# bash refer the argument/variable piped in

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, pipe

How to refer the argument piped in?

For example, if you have a code `test.sh` as below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

when you run `./test.sh abcd.txt`, you will get abcd.txt printed on screen.

But when I try `ls *.txt | ./test.sh`, I got all echoes empty lines.

Comment: STDIN != command line arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 -I xxx ./test.sh xxx
```

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you! I thougth I remember once I got into trouble without `´` ...  I notice once also The -I thing but I did not found info about it. I planed to test this further.

Comment: @EtanReisner the answer has been edited after tests, the `-I xxx` had been kept, otherwise this is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Data "piped in" is STDIN, but those are not command-line arguments.  Here's an example printing each line of STDIN:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
  echo "Line: $line"
done
```

There are *many* options to the Bash `read` command.  Read the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section of the man page for more info.